# Cannot connect to local db in .net core app via kestrel server

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm building an API in .NET 5.0 (core) and have run into a problem connecting to a database on my local SQL server instance.

My previous projects have been ASP.Net running on IIS and issues like this have been typically resolved by changing app pool permissions etc. (I think this is a permission issue also).

The problem is I have no idea how to resolve this when the app is running using the Kestrel web server so there is no 'IIS app pool' thing that I know of to change.

I can connect to the database via VS and SMSS, and I've used the formers connection string in my application yet no matter what I try I get the following error;

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x89C50107): Unknown error (0x89c50107)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1082
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 725
   at {app_name}.Logic.AppServices.Test.GetAllUsersTestQuery.GetAllUsersTestQueryHandler.Handle(GetAllUsersTestQuery query) in {app_path}\{app_name}.Logic\AppServices\Test\GetAllUsersTestQuery.cs:line 51
   at {app_name}.Web.Controllers.TestController.GetDbTest() in {apppath}\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:-1983577849,State:0,Class:20
```

Working connection string in VS2019;

[image: Example working connection in VS]

I think I should also note that the project started as a learning of CQRS pattern but when I realised the limitations of using EF against my existing (non EF created) database with it's stored procedures, I'm attempting to bypass EF and am using Dapper to connect directly to the database. So this is still a test though, I'm literally just doing a select * from a table for now - just to see if this will work at all.

**UPDATE**

Finally noticed this discrepancy and searched for the other connnection string... totally forgot about appSetting.Development.json. ARGH!!

Connection string in appSettings.json;
[image: Connection string in appSettings.json]

Connection string being used by .Logic project;
[image: Connection string in process]

So I fixed that but now I get a login error for user blank. Hmm...

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

I had suspected this might be an issue all along however, why can I not connect anonomously like VS appears to do?

This BTW is running in debug mode under VS2019 using the Kestrel server. From what I can see in Task Manager it's running under my account so should have full admin rights.

**UPDATE 2**

Found the issue, I needed to set "Integrated Security" back to True on my connection string, reversing an earlier change for debugging purposes to see what would happen.

Comment: Instead of posting your error message as an image, post it as formatted text.  Easier for us to read and allows it to be searched on.

Comment: Whoops good point @Devon, that's what happens when you post a question in frustration at 1:30am. Sigh.

Comment: How are you passing your connection string in your application?

Comment: Being it's a CQRS pattern app that I'm learning, that's a bit complicated to explain for me :P

What I have noticed though is the connection string I have in my API project (where the connection string is defined) does not match the connection string being used in my .Logic project - which is weird - because I have only defined it in one place in the entire solution. Hmmm...

I've shown the setting vs what I'm seeing in the OQ above...

Comment: Got it... needed to set Integrated Security back to True. Earlier debugging change to see what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first things first, thank you @devon for pointing me in the right direction with that simple question "How are you passing your connection string in your application?".

That was enough to trigger some further debug steps I should have done earlier.

**The solution was - the simple thing - doh!;**

1. I had forgotten about the appsetting.Development.json sub file, so conveniently hidden away there in the UI by default. That's where the actual connection string my app was using was defined - and no I do not recall filling that out - but it has been a few weeks since I started this process and I've been away from it for a few weeks due to life.

[image]

2. Then in the process of trying things out to resolve the connection issue I had changed the Integrated Security property on my Connection String to false to see what would happen. I didn't expect it to help, but I also intended to change it back but forgot. A good lesson there.